# Getting error "The JWT issuer 'http://localhost:9090/realms/ditto' is not supported" from eclipse ditto

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to integrate keycloak with eclipse ditto according to official document https://eclipse.dev/ditto/installation-operating.html#openid-connect and when i'm trying to access ditto api getting below error :

{
"status": 401,
"error": "gateway:jwt.issuer.notsupported",
"message": "The JWT issuer 'http://localhost:9090/realms/ditto' is not supported.",
"description": "Check if your JWT is correct."
}